# Forcing Settings into Action Overflow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-actionbar, android-menu

I am currently trying to add a a settings into my application but I don't want it on my action bar as it says in the android developer documentation that settings should always be in the action overflow towards the bottom.
My question to you is can you force it to be in the action overflow even though there are no other action buttons and tons of room in the bar?
I have tried doing this

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

but this just makes it so you have to push the hardware menu button.
Is there an easy way of doing this that I am missing?

Any help would be much appreciated

Disco

Comment: Have you tested `showAsAction="never"` on a phone without a dedicated hardware menu button?

Comment: Yes I have and it still isn't shown in the overflow, only when the hardware menu button is pressed

Comment: How exactly did you test on a phone **without** a hardware menu button if you press the menu button to get that Setting menu item? Anyway, if you test in the emulator for `Honeycomb`(for tablets without any hardware buttons) the Settings menu with *showAsAction* `never` it will always be placed in the overflow menu. I think what you're seeing is the default behavior for phones with menu buttons and I don't know if you can modify it.

Comment: Thanks @Luksprog. you're right. I used a few different emulators and the behaviour was as you described. With a hardware button the overflow isn't shown but without there is the overflow menu. Works pretty nicely

Comment: @Luksprog if you want to post your suggestion as an answer I can accept it

Comment: Posted an answer, hope it's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you test in the emulator for `Honeycomb`(for tablets without any hardware buttons) the Settings menu with `showAsAction` *never* it will always be placed in the overflow menu. I think what you're seeing is the default behavior for phones with menu buttons and I don't know if you can modify it.